# Unable to debug emails

Tags: email

I created a method which prints the email body to the console, but I am unable to view it.

```
public void createCaseCommentFromEmail(){
    for (EmailMessage em : (List<EmailMessage>) Trigger.new) {
            System.debug('Email HTML Body: '+ em.HtmlBody);
            System.debug('Email Text Body: '+ em.TextBody);
    }            
}
```

I'm sending the email to a routing address (configured via Email-to-Case) so I set the debug log on the class above (EmailHandler.cls) but nothing appears in the debug logs section nor in the developer console.

How can one debug incoming/outgoing emails?

Comment: who is the user that is running the Email-to-Case? Sometimes, is the System. you should change for your user..

Comment: I am the one who created the routing address via Setup>Email-To-Case, so I suppose that I'm the running user. no system user

Comment: the default, is the system user....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the **Automated Case User**  in Support Setting for your user:

[image]

Also, you could get reference here -> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004634&type=1

Comment: That was it, thanks!